# Move element in list TCL

Tags: tcl

I have a two problems with my script in TCL language. 
First:
I created list which download values from chart, but i dont know how to move elements in my list, for example:

```
set list [2,3,4,5,6] # my list
```

and i want this effect ->

```
[1,2,3,4,5] next -> [0,1,2,3,4] etc.
```

Second:
How to create fixed size list for 10 elements? I want 10 elements in my list and when i got > 10 elements i want to remove last element and add new as first element (first problem)

Thanks and sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a new item in the first position in the list, and at the same time limit the list to a given size:

```
set size 5
set list [list 2 3 4 5 6]
# => 2 3 4 5 6
set list [lrange [linsert $list 0 1] 0 $size-1]
# => 1 2 3 4 5
set list [lrange [linsert $list 0 0] 0 $size-1]
# => 0 1 2 3 4
```

You can simplify this a bit using a procedure:

```
proc move {varName new} {
    upvar 1 $varName list
    set size 5
    set list [lrange [linsert $list 0 $new] 0 $size-1]
}

set list [list 2 3 4 5 6]
# => 2 3 4 5 6
move list 1
# => 1 2 3 4 5
move list 0
# => 0 1 2 3 4
```

Documentation:
[linsert](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/linsert.htm),
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[lrange](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrange.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[upvar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/upvar.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl index expressions:*

- *integer* zero-based index number
- `end` the last element
- `end`*-N* the *n*th element before the last element
- `end`*+N* the *n*th element after the last element (in practice, *N* should be negative)
- *M-N* the *n*th element before element *m*
- *M+N* the *n*th element after element *m*

There can be no whitespace within the expression.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Its working :) You are the best!
Regards,
Michal

Comment: Older versions of Tcl don't support the _M±N_ syntax for indices; you have to work it out with `expr` in that case.